# How can i declare MPI_COMM_WORLD so that I can use it everywhere?

Tags: c, mpi

You can notice that the code is instantiated in MPI_COMM_WORLD but is being used in function send_code!

my codes are:

```
int send_code(char *code)
{
        //produce the codes for adding the code into the table
        printf("%s\n",code);
        MPI_Send(code, 8, MPI_CHAR,0, 0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        MPI_Status status;
        int outbuf, inbuf;

        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        if (rank==0)
        {
               MPI_Recv(code, 8, MPI_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
               printf("%s by master\n",code);

        }
        else
        {
                ........
        }

        MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking about the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` in MPI, it is declared in `mpi.h` and defined somewhere in one of the MPI implementation's libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Static global variable? If that is safe enough for you and you are ready to bear the risks ;-)

Comment: I don't know how complex your code is, you have to be extra careful with every global state you introduce. But if this is all you need to do, that one global variable can't do anything wrong...